# Backing up and reloading console command history

Tags: c#, console, history

When using a C# console app, all the commands I input get buffered during the life of the session (ie. until I close the Console).
I would now like to be able to back up this buffer and retrieve it next time I relaunch my console app.
I have read a few threads on SOF and got some pointer to "SetConsoleHistoryInfo", but I am not sure that is the way to go, nor how to use it for that matter.
Has anyone ever done something similar?

Answer (score -1):

You could read each command you input and save it into a `.txt` file. If you are writing directly to the console you can save the string from the `Console.ReadLine()` function into a variable and then write it to the historical file.

The next time you run your program, have a method that checks the `.txt` file and retrieves the commands in whatever format you desire (array, line by line etc.)

This gives you flexibility as to how you manage the `.txt` file as well, you can keep the historical commands from every time your program has run or just the previous execution.

Comment: You didnt give the answer how to access commands using Up and Down buttons